# Hex calculating unwantedly

Tags: php

I have a PHP script which will output a random file name, but I have the file names named with hex numbers, and PHP apparently calculates HEX and outputs it in regular numbers. The image shows correctly, but the echo where it displays it in an h3 tag doesn't work. Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

When I look in the Inspect Element i see the source of the image as the hex correctly.

Example:

Image source `src="MemeDatabase/0000023E.jpg"`

Text shows up as `574`

```
$dir = 'MemeDatabase';
$fileNames = array();
if(is_dir($dir)){
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
        if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && is_readable($dir.'/'.$file)){
            $fileNames[] = $file;
        }
    }
closedir($handle);
$fileName = array_rand($fileNames); 
$withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $fileName);
echo "<a href=\"index.php\"><img src=\"MemeDatabase/$fileNames[$fileName]\"></a>";

} else {
    echo "<p>There is an directory read issue</p>";
}

if(!isset($_COOKIE["0ShowUsage"])) {
    echo "<h2>Click the image to proceed to the next meme</h2>";
    setcookie("0ShowUsage", "False", time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
} else {
echo "<h3>$withoutExt</h3>";
}
```

Comment: `$fileName` contains key to the `$fileNames` array, not the filename itself. Seems to be just coincidence that it has value 574, You probably have every single file from 1, so the 574th file is `0000023E.jpg`. Use `$fileNames[$fileName]` in the preg_replace().

Comment: OHH! Thank you very much! This fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

If the hex number is preceded by `%`, this will be treated as a hex code when parsing the URL, not by PHP. You need to use `urlencode()` to encode it properly.

```
echo "<a href=\"index.php\"><img src=\"MemeDatabase/" . urlencode($fileNames[$fileName]) . "\"></a>";
```

Comment: No, the url is perfectly working, it's the $withoutExt variable which gets calculated into normal nubmers

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that would happen. Could you add specific examples of filenames and the output you're seeing to the question?

Comment: The files have a unique ID counting from 0 to infinite in HEX. A file name could be 0000007A.jpg would output 122.jpg on the echo within the h3 tag. Maybe it has to do with HTML? It just seems more logical that it's the PHP scripts fault

Comment: What do you see when you do View Source in the browser? Please edit the question and fill in all the details.

Comment: So when you use `View Source` you see `<h3>574</h3>`?

Comment: I did yes, but Roman Hocke figured out that it was caused by me using the wrong variable. Sorry for the inconvenience.